# Сортировка значений по убыванию из базы данных для дискорд бота

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, discord

Я делаю таблицу лидеров по деньгам хочу сделать пока-что топ 10, в базе данных у меня занесено 3 пользователя на скрине видно что они выведены из бд, но значения не выводятся почему-то объясните, что в моем коде не так вроде все правильно сделал.Можно желательно кодом помочь если это возможно. Билиотека discord.net фреймворк ef core

```
 public async Task RichUsers()
        {
            var eb = new EmbedBuilder();
            var RichUsersMoneys = (await BalanceDb.GetAllMoney(Context.Guild.Id));
            
            IEnumerable<Balance> ds = RichUsersMoneys.OrderByDescending(x => x.Amount);
            foreach (var str in ds)
                eb.AddField("Топ богатейших пользователей сервера", $"{str}");

            await ReplyAsync(embed: eb.Build());

        }
 public static async Task<List<Balance>> GetAllMoney(ulong guildId)
        {
            using var db = new SqlDbContext();
            IQueryable<Balance> ds = db.Money;
            return await ds.Where(x => x.GuildId == guildId).ToListAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Для начала я бы проверил, что у вас лежит в `Context.Guild.Id` и есть ли запись в таблице `Money` с таким `GuildId`

Comment: @CrazyElf Context.Guild.Id это от библиотеки поля, Money это от фреймворка название таблицы  public DbSet<Balance> Money { get; set; } в самой таблице есть Столбец с название GuildId он берет айди канала на котором отсылается сообщение

Comment: Вопрос не в том, откуда что, а вы проверьте что у вас реально там находится. Какие значения в базе и какое значение в этой штуке. Может там такое значение, которого нет в базе (а дальше можно разбираться в причинах уже).

Comment: str - это экземпляр Balance, а вы его в строку конвертируете. Убедитесь что метод Balance.ToString переопределен и возвращает то что вы ожидаете, а не пустую строку.